# Property 'rotation' does not exist on type 'never' in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-three-fiber

I am starting learning "React Three Fiber" with TypeScript,
but when I started my journey, I got stuck with this problem. I've searched a lot on internet but didn't find my answer.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";


const AnimatedBox() {
  const meshRef = useRef();
      useFrame(()=>{
          console.log("hi");
          if(meshRef.current){
          meshRef.current.rotation += 0.01;


          }
      });
    
    return (

          <mesh ref = {meshRef} scale={[0.5, 0.5 ,0.5]}>
            <boxGeometry />
            <meshStandardMaterial  />

          </mesh>

    );
  }

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas>
        <AnimatedBox />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
        <directionalLight />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Every time I run this code I got this error:

> Property 'rotation' does not exist on type 'never'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three's Documentation explains [how to tackle this issue](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/typescript)

> React's `useRef` won't automatically infer types despite pointing it
> to a typed ref.
>
> You can type the ref yourself by passing an type through useRef's
> generics
>
> The exclamation mark is a
> non-null assertion that will let TS know that ref.current is defined
> when we access it in effects.

In your case that would be something like:

```
import { Mesh } from 'three'

const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>(null!)
```

Comment: Is your file having the correct extension? `.tsx` ? . Maybe try importing three as follows: `import * as THREE from 'three'`, and then use it as such : `useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There was an error in import THREE, I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Add a type to useRef

```
const meshRef = useRef<HTMLElement>()
```

Answer (score 0):

A year later, but anyway, I left this here if anyone else lands here looking for a solution

TLDR; Install the package @types/three, so you can do something like this, without errors.

```
npm install @types/three

import { Mesh } from 'three'

const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>(null!) // This avoids the error: ref.current is possibly 'undefined' error
```

The why explanation:

When using TypeScript with the three.js library, it's possible to encounter errors when trying to access the properties and methods of the Mesh class, for example, the rotation method. TypeScript doesn't recognize these types and may generate errors when attempting to use them.

Solution:
To solve this problem, install the @types/three package, which provides TypeScript type definitions for the three.js library. This allows TypeScript to understand and verify the code you're writing, including the properties and methods of the Mesh class.